# Klein PHP router - can't get it to work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm tryin to use Klein for some routing on my test webapp.

I have mod_rewrite enabled and that's my htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I'm using their Hello World example, but i get a 404 when i type 'localhost/mysite/hello-world'.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are running the application in a sub-directory `localhost/mysite`, right?

Comment: Correct :) (My .htaccess is inside the subdir)

Comment: Than use `RewriteBase` ;)

Comment: Still a 404. :(

Comment: Have you tried to start the app with the php build-in webserver?
```cd c:\xampp\htdocs\my-app\public
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080```

Then open `http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the manual about this topic:

Sub Directory Installation: https://github.com/klein/klein.php/wiki/Sub-Directory-Installation

2. Option: You can try to run it with PHP's built-in webserver:

$ cd [my-app-name]; php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php

Comment: Thank you, that's what i needed.